# OAuth2Client #import "NXOAuth2.h" File Not Found

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, object, oauth

I'm trying to add OAuth2Client to a project. I have followed all the directions listed [here](https://github.com/nxtbgthng/oauth2client), but I get `NXOAuth2.h" File Not Found` error when I try to `import "NXOAuth2.h`. The odd thing is that Xcode will escape complete this header, but then immediately give the error after it is entered.

If it helps, I can upload a new program with just my OAuth2Client addition attempts to github.

Header Search Paths
[image: Header Search Paths]

Link Binary With Libraries
[image: Link Binary With Libraries]

Public Headers on OAuth2Client Build Phases
[image: Public Headers on OAuth2Client Build Phases]

Comment: Is your header search path filled out?

Comment: I believe so. I added some screen shots of how I tried following the steps in the Readme.

Comment: Did you fix this in the end?

Answer (score 4):

The user header search path you have there doesn't look right to me. It should be set to "$(SRCROOT)/path/to/the/external/library/OAuth2Client". This then resolves to the ACTUAL path you want to search for header files.

[image]

Also ensure you have followed all the steps outlined in the Read me.
i.e. added the target of the NXOAuth2Client as a Target Dependancy

[image]

Comment: Is libOAuth2Client.a supposed to be red?